# java - "int cannot be converted to ArrayList"

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int

I'm trying to create a two dimensional ArrayList which will store ints, strings & booleans.

I've got as far as entering the first int, but I get a red squiggle and the error "int cannot be converted to ArrayList".

```
    ArrayList[][] qarray= new ArrayList [10][5];

    qarray[0][0]= 1;
```

BTW, googling the phrase "int cannot be converted to ArrayList" is giving me exactly six results.

Comment: "I'm trying to create a two dimensional ArrayList which will store ints, strings & booleans" <-- wait, what? You have a design problem here

Comment: @david, if you can expand a bit more on what you are using this for then maybe we can help you with a better design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ArrayList[][] qarray= new ArrayList [10][5];**

Basically your code creates 2 dimensional array list objects (50 array list objects).

**qarray[0][0]= 1;**

And you are trying to assign integer, where you need to create a ArrayList object. It expects something like

```
     qarray[0][0]= new ArrayList();
```

However this would not meet your objective. The following piece of code could meet your objectives:

```
    ArrayList[] qarray = new ArrayList[10];
    qarray[0]= new ArrayList();
    qarray[0].add(1);

    qarray[1]= new ArrayList();
    qarray[1].add(true);

    qarray[2]= new ArrayList();
    qarray[2].add("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct.

Your array type is ArrayList. You can insert only ArrayLists in that array.

If you want to store int's, your declaration should be.

```
int[][] qarray= new int [10][5];
```

And also, as someone commented, you cannot store strings and booleans in this array anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
List<Integer> qarray = new ArrayList<>();
qarray.add(1);
```

Comment: Looking for multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(1);
```

Comment: Looking for multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

According to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays), you can not create arrays of ArrayList. Use 2D array instead.

If you need 2D `ArrayList` anyway, you should have tried this way:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);

ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(5);

listOfLists.add(list1);
listOfLists.add(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I believe that you need array and not ArrayList. 2d array can be created  as following.

```
int[][] arr = new int [10][10];
```

Your next problem is that you tried to assign int constant 1 to variable of other type. The following  example shows how to assign int to element of array

```
arr [0][0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you wan to add int,String and boolean then you can use

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

it will help you

Comment: when you used generic as Obejct then you can store all the data type in inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer>[][] list = new ArrayList[10][10];
 list[0][0] = new ArrayList<>();
list[0][0].add(new Integer(10);
```

try like this.